# how to include first element of a list before computing the difference

Tags: python, list, dictionary, histogram

I'm creating a histogram. I currently have this block of code:

```
g = [479, 481, 503, 525, 554, 586, 614, 669, 683]
```

and then i've written this for the x and y axis:

```
x =[28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20]
y = diff(g)
```

This is what it computes y as:

```
array([  2,  22,  22,  29,  32,  28,  55,  14])
```

However, I realized that my histogram doesn't include 479 (first element in g) before it starts computing the difference from there onwards, which is what I was hoping to do. My desired output is

```
array([ 479, 2,  22,  22,  29,  32,  28,  55,  14])
```

Is there a way that I can do this? I don't want to manually append it as I need to automate it for various files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways of prepending elements to a [diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html): before or after the fact. If you want to prepend a zero before, you can use the the `prepend` argument available as of v1.16.0:

```
y = np.diff(g, prepend=0)
```

This is equivalent to manually inserting a zero into your array (in case your version of numpy is older):

```
y = np.diff(np.insert(g, 0, 0))
```

You can do something very similar after the diff, by inserting `g[0]` into the beginning:

```
y = np.insert(np.diff(g), 0, g[0])
```

However, all the options shown here are inefficient because they copy all your data (`g` or the diff). A space-efficient solution would allocate an output buffer, and compute the difference manually:

```
y = np.empty_like(g)
y[1:] = g[1:] - g[:-1]
y[0] = g[0]
```